# Uwsgi: doesn't work with django's settings as a package

Tags: python, django, deployment, settings, uwsgi

I'm trying split django's setting using package, impressed at [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#SimplePackageOrganizationforEnvironments) article.

My problem is uwsgi don't recognize my project.settings package.

*[some lyrics]
With secrets.py i'm slighty modified structure, so all file except secrets.py stored in github, and secret.py managed by ansible.*

So my setting now is a package with following structure:

```
project/
├── manage.py
└── project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── defaults.py
    │   ├── development.py
    │   ├── production.py
    │   ├── staging.py
    │   └── secrets.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Contents of important files:

**settings/__init__.py**

```
# Appropriate config load based on DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT env 
# variable, which set at system boot

ENVIRONMENT = os.getenv("DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT")

if ENVIRONMENT == "production":
    from production import *
elif ENVIRONMENT == "staging":
    from staging import *
elif ENVIRONMENT == "development":
    from development import *
```

**settings/development.py**

```
from .defaults import *

DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'debug_toolbar',
)
```

**settings/defaults.py**

```
import os
import secrets

SECRET_KEY = secrets.SECRET_KEY

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': secrets.DATABASE_NAME,
        'USER': secrets.DATABASE_USER,
        'PASSWORD': secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# and so on, almost default
```

**settings/secrets.py**

```
SECRET_KEY = '1YdCOUsWeKk&BWDa$PI6X1@IdUH5vjkjcB^v&k3J@*fRRVRPrW'

DATABASE_NAME = 'mydb'
DATABASE_USER = 'myuser'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = '1l3S7KURpd1MYPOr'
```

**DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT**

```
$ echo $DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT
development
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

At this poing, I can start `manage runserver` and `check` without issues:

```
$ python manage.py check
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

But, if I try use UWSGI, I'm got the error in uwsgi-error.log (my project name is pdfupload):

```
[uwsgi-daemons] respawning "python /home/vagrant/pdfupload/manage.py rqworker default" (uid: 1000 gid: 1000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/pdfupload/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 182, in fetch_command
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 113, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Obviously, uwsgi can't read django's settings due import error.

There is uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/home/vagrant/pdfupload
master=True
disable-logging=False
chmod-socket = 777
chown-socket = vagrant

logto      = /home/vagrant/log/uwsgi.log
req-logger = file:/home/vagrant/log/uwsgi-access.log
logger     = file:/home/vagrant/log/uwsgi-error.log

vacuum=True
pidfile=/run/uwsgi/pdfupload.pid
max-requests=5000
socket=/run/uwsgi/pdfupload.socket
processes=2
harakiri=20

pythonpath=..
env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=pdfupload.settings
module = django.core.wsgi:get_wsgi_application()
touch-reload=/tmp/pdfupload.reload
```

Virtual environment doesn't using.

Please help me finish this setup up.

Answer (score 0):

Your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE must point to actual settings file, so in your case :

```
pdfupload.settings.defaults (or whatever in your settings folder)
```